# How to enable IAP for k8s on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

**Aim:** to enable Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) in conjunction with Kubernetes (k8s).

**Methods:**

- Two apps were deployed
- A SSL load balancer was put in front
- When one navigates to domain/app1, app1 is shown
- This tutorial was followed to enable IAP for k8s https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto

**Results**

- The Google login screen appears when one navigates to domain/app1
- When the login succeeds a ‘default gateway - 404’ is shown instead of the app when IAP is disabled

**Discussion**

- Should a redirect not be configured somewhere? When the authentication and authorization succeeds a URI _gcp_gatekeeper/authenticate was added and a 404 was returned, while a redirect to the app should be done right?
- When an App engine is deployed, IAP is enable the IAP works out of the box. What makes this deploy different? Perhaps App Engine contains some elements that are omitted in k8s.

**Current problem**

When the authentication succeeds the following error is shown:

```
There was a problem with your request. Error code 11
```

Comment: Can you add the configuration yaml files to your question? It could help to reproduce your case and hopefully find a solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this use case? I'm also having trouble configuring multiple IAP-protected backends under non-default paths.

Comment: Actually you can now do this natively through Ingress!
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with,  here’s some general information:

To get started with IAP in GCP, add an [App Engine app](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/appengine) or configure [Cloud Load Balancer for IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto). In case you are running Kubernetes cluster, you may have the Load Balancer configured already.

Then you should enable IAP for it here: `Menu -> Security -> Identity-Aware Proxy`

And finally, that is the place where redirect URI can be configured. You can get there from previous step by selecting triple dot on the right side of your App/LB and choosing `Edit OAuth Client`.

```
Menu -> APIs & Services -> Credentials
```

Create `OAuth clientID` and set `Authorized redirect URIs` for it.

> **Authorized redirect URIs**
>   For use with requests from a web server. This
>   is the path in your application that users are redirected to after
>   they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with
>   the authorization code for access. Must have a protocol. Cannot
>   contain URL fragments or relative paths. Cannot be a public IP
>   address.

For *App Engine* apps this value is predefined, but you can adjust it according to your needs.

Comment: It should be `https://<some-domain>/_gcp_gatekeeper/authenticate` right? This setting does not redirect to the app, but is required to authenticate or is this incorrect? At the moment a 404 - default gateway is shown. When IAP is disabled the app appears again. What is missing?